# Default ispconfig 3 website page doesn't show

Tags: vmware, centos, apache-http-server

I am not a professional Linux user. I want to use ISPConfig 3 so I installed php and MariaDB on CentOS 6.3 on a vmware guest OS.
Then I installed ISPConfig 3 too (on port 8080). But when I enter https://x.x.x.x:8080 on host OS (x.x.x.x is the ip of guest OS), default page for apache is shown (Apache 2 Test page).
How could I open ISPConfig control panel page?

Answer (score -1):

1. Disable the default site
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   a2dissite default
   ```
3. Restart Apache

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It seems on-topic and answers the question.